# C CreateProcess exec system command

Tags: c, windows, createprocess

**C BEGINNER WARNING!!!**
I am writing an application in c, that is supposed to run a user defined command in the context of "cmd.exe" and write the output to a variable. For example if the command variable was "dir C:\" the c programm should use CreateProcess() to start cmd.exe, input "dir C:\" and return the output to a variable. As of right now the code i have so far is:

```
char cmmndoutput[256];
char userdefcmmnd[256] = "dir C:\\";
STARTUPINFO sui;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&sui, 0,sizeof(sui));
sui.cb = sizeof(sui);
sui.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
sui.hStdInput = userdefcmmnd[];
sui.hStdOutput = cmmndoutput[];
TCHAR cmdvar[256] = "cmd.exe";
CreateProcess(cmdvar, userdefcmmnd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sui, &pi);

// wait 5 seconds or program exit somehow

printf("%s",cmmndoutput[]); // or do something with the output
```

Note: The programm should wait a specific time for the command and should **not** wait until cmd.exe exits like system() would.

Thanks for your patience, i am new to c and have definetly got alot of things wrong in this code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The optional `lpApplicationName` parameter is not searched for on `PATH`. It must be a qualified path, either relative to the working directory or a fully-qualified path (e.g. expanded `"%ComSpec%"` or `"%SystemRoot%\\System32\\cmd.exe"`). Also, using it doesn't mean you're free to leave out the command and options from the command line. `lpCommandLine` should be `"cmd /c dir C:\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sui.hStdInput = userdefcmmnd[];
sui.hStdOutput = cmmndoutput[];
```

`hStdInput` and `hStdOutput` aren't arrays. They take handles, typically the result of `CreatePipe()` but file handles could be used as well.

The general form is to use two or three calls `CreatePipe()` with a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` with `bInheritHandles = TRUE` and `SetHandleInformation()` on the side not being redirected to prevent it from being forwarded. The handles from `CreatePipe()` can be converted to `FILE *` objets by `_open_osfhandle()` followed by `_fdopen()`.

You won't be able to use `FILE *` objects on your read side because of your five second timeout requirement. Pipe handles and background streams are tricky business. The only way I've gotten timeouts to work right is to use a background thread to read the pipe input with `ReadFile()` and use `CancelIoEx()` to give up when timeout is reached.

And you claim to be a beginning C programmer. I am sorry. The number of advanced topics this code invokes the advanced topics of multi-process, multi-threading, and the slight buggyness and general complexity of the bottom-level IO of Windows. If you can get out of doing this you will be happier.

Comment: Remember to close the parent's copy of the child's inherited `hStdOutput` pipe handle immediately after `CreateProcess` returns. The pipe won't close so long as there are potential writers. That said, the child may create another process and leak the handle, in which case canceling the read may be the only option. Also, if you're using multiple pipes to communicate with the child over standard I/O, then you need to do something to avoid deadlock, such as using separate threads to read the child's stdout and stderr.

Comment: thanks for your responses, i will try to use pipes to get the IO working!